# is it posible to not to show all poped screens when using popUntil?

Tags: flutter, dart

when I use
 `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/myPage))`
all screens that are being poped appears until I get the "myPage" screen
is there any way to only show myPage screen without the poped screens

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)

It will allow you to push the route you want and remove all routes stacked till the predicate returns true.